# SQL get First day of month 3 months before current Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to select the first day of the month 3 months before the current date.

so for example if the current date was: '2015-11-08' 
my result would want to be: '2015-08-01'

I would prefer if this was in yyyy-mm-dd format.

I tried this to start with but had no luck:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY('2015-09-01') + 1, @today)
```

I have tried numerous things but cannot seem to crack it, any advice or help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, show what you have attempted.

Comment: No worries, done it.

Comment: What have you tried, and where does it fail ? (I have my idea about the last part)

Comment: I have been trying to do it with 'SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY('2015-09-01') + 1, @today)'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The logic is simple:

- Subtract the day of the month minus 1 days from the date
- Subtract three months

In SQL Server:

```
select dateadd(month, -3, dateadd(day, 1 - day(dte), dte))
```

For the current date:

```
select cast(dateadd(month, -3, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())) as date)
```

And as a string:

```
select convert(varchar(10),
               dateadd(month, -3, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())),
               120)
```

Comment: This has helped me a lot, Works Perfect.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,i didn't came across Day function

Answer (score 0):

select dateadd(month, -3, dateadd(day, -2, '2014-09-03'))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).